# Go Nginx Websocket "Connection closed before receiving a handshake response"

Tags: go, nginx, websocket

I have a Go web server running on my localhost. I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy to change the protocol to `ws` when a certain route is accessed on my server.

I keep getting this error message in my browser - `(index):13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response`

In addition, the Go server keeps printing this error - `read tcp [::1]:8080->[::1]:59967: read: connection reset by peer`

I've tried a number of combinations in my nginx.conf file. I can't seem to get any of them to work.

Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func reader(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(string(p))

        if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }

    }
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Home Page")
}

func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World")
    ws, err := websocket.Upgrade(w, r, nil, 1024, 1024)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Could not open websocket connection", http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("Client Connected")

    err = ws.WriteMessage(1, []byte("Hi Client!"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error")
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    reader(ws)
}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", wsEndpoint)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
    setupRoutes()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Go WebSocket Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>

    <script>
      let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws");
      console.log("Attempting Connection...");

      socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log("Successfully Connected");
        socket.send("Hi From the Client!");
      };

      socket.onmessage = msg => {
        console.log(msg);
      };

      socket.onclose = event => {
        console.log("Socket Closed Connection: ", event);
        socket.send("Client Closed!");
      };

      socket.onerror = error => {
        console.log("Socket Error: ", error);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

nginx.conf

```
  {
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /ws {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/ws;
          proxy_redirect off;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

        location / {
            # root   html;
            # index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting the websocket connection to stay open indefinitely. I don't know what exactly is closing it and why.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong are much appreciated.

Comment: NGINX is in that port? 8080? This is correct? I known that is 80! Instead of 8080, try 80! 
Expected flow: client requests for 80 (NGINX), NGINX forward to Server in 8080, confirm connection and response.

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia The nginx config is set to listen on 8080 (first directive in the `server` block).

Comment: Server and NGINX in same ports?

Comment: @AristofanioGarcia I don't think NGINX is running on 8080 in addition to the server. If so, I wouldn't be able to start one of them. Either way, I tried it as ```listen 80``` and got the same error, ```(index):13 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1/ws' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response```